# foreach for dynamic type C# - dynamic casting? reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic-programming, late-binding

I defined various classes like this:

```
public class Subclass<T> : BaseObject<T>, IObject, IObject<T> { ... }
```

`BaseObject<T>` contains all the functionality I need.  `IObject<T>` allows it to be accessed between projects.  `IObject` allows collections to be created: `List<IObject>`.

`BaseObject<T>` and `IObject<T>` have a property `T Value`;

So I have

```
public class BaseObject<T>  // T is double, int, decimal, long, short, int - in fact anything enumerable
    : IObject, IObject<T>
{
    [...]
    T Value;
    [...]
}
```

The problem I am trying to solve is how to unpack this by type `T`.

I want to write this function but don't know how in C#:

```
public void DoProcessing(List<IObject> objectsToBeProcessed)
{
    foreach(dynamic singleObject in objectsToBeProcessed)
    {
        Type unpackedType = [somehow retrieve the type]
        BaseObject<unpackedType.GetType()> unpackedObject = [do some kind of conversion of singleObject];
        ProcessorClass<unpackedType.GetType()> processor = new ProcessorClass<unpackedType.GetType()>();
        processor.Process(unpackedObject);
    }
}
```

I'm finding this quite hard to put into words but I hope that this explanation gets the idea across.  Basically I lose the type information when I build the `List<IObject>` and I need it back later on when I pass it across into another assembly.  I want a single central `DoProcessing` method that can then delegate by type to instances of generics.

How can I get the type information back?

I understand that generics need a type known at compile-time.  But this is situation where you only know the type at runtime.  The dynamic keyword allows the collection to be iterated, but I haven't found a way to create the bit inside the loop.

Or should I just force everything to a `double` in `BaseObject` and then cast it back locally in some way?

I'm a bit lost on this and feel I am missing something obvious.  Any ideas welcome.

**POSTSCRIPT - CLARIFICATION**

The purpose of this is to separate the code-base into two assemblies:

1. The assembly with `BaseObject<T>` allows customers and third parties
   to write their own business logic which we don't need to see.  They
   simply subclass the BaseObject into their own code.
2. The assembly with `IObject` & `IObject<T>` contains generic business
   logic that we are creating.

We need this separation in so customers can develop their own libraries of code without having to submit it to us.  They just send us a list of `List<IObject>` and we do the rest, calling their subclasses back as necessary.

Surely it is possible!

**ALTERNATIVELY**

Can anyone suggest a better architectural solution to the two assembly solution I have described i.e. concrete classes in customer code assembly & abstract/interfaces in our framework assembly.

**SOLUTION**

OK so I've found a simpler solution.  Late-binding via Reflection is doable but is hard to implement with my nuanced object model.

Instead, I have replaced the generic type `T` and implemented a property which is an enum of

```
public enum ValueType
{
    Double,
    Boolean,
    Integer,
    ...
}
```

I then implement overloaded constructors, added this property to the non-generic interface `IObject` and have removed the generic interface `IObject<T>` as it's no longer needed.

Returning the value as `double` or `bool` is then handled by

```
public double AsDouble();
public bool AsBoolean();
public int AsInt();
...
```

in the interface.

It's not elegant or theoretically pure but it means I don't lose type information and can treat instances all the same.  I just unpack the ValueType and choose different behaviour programmatically.  It also avoids using the `dynamic` keyword as all values are implemented as `double` so looping is easy to implement.

On the plus side I have removed a lot of constraints on generics as they were needed up the inheritance hierarchy.  It was getting really complicated and the compilation errors were getting too difficult to unravel.

It feels a bit unsatisfactory from a purist perspective, but MongoDB does something similar so that's good enough for me.

I do feel however that C# is "unfinished" in this area and needs a way to upcast or downcast more easily.  It's just such an obvious thing to add.

Maybe the Reflection can be wrapped up somehow to make it transparent to the programmer.

Over-engineering, pragmatism and purism.  These are the things that weigh on me...

Comment: Is this of any use?    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-examine-and-instantiate-generic-types-with-reflection

Comment: You will have to use some reflection to do that, dynamic alone is not enough.

Comment: I am not an expert on reflection - never used it.  Can you give me some pointers?

Comment: Mmmm let me check into that!

Comment: Still some learning to do but it looks like "late-binding with reflection" is the answer.  Will mark the question as answered once I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough to return the type of the object inside your loop:

```
Type unpackedType = singleObject.GetType();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Yes, it does - but I can't then pass that in as a parameter type to a generic i.e. Processor<unpackedType> fails, as does Processor<typeof(unpackedType)>.